# How do I add a column to a data frame in R that uses information from multiple columns and rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr, sapply

I am trying to add a column to my data frame **Bus78*uniM***, called **travel_time** that contains the time difference between two adjacent rows, plus the difference in the deviation. In order to do this so far I have created a function **Trav_time**, which takes four inputs; the dataset, row number, and column numbers that are being used:

> ```
> Trav_time = function(df,i,j,k){
>   
>   if((df[i,1]-df[i-1,1])==2){
>     trav_time = as.numeric(df[i,j]+df[i,k]-df[i-1,j]-df[i-1,k])
>     return(trav_time)
>   }
>   else if((df[i,1]-df[i-1,1])==5){
>     trav_time = as.numeric(df[i,j]+df[i,k]-df[i-1,j]-df[i-1,k])
>     return(trav_time)
>   }
>   else{
>     return(NA)
>   }
> }
> ```

The function returns the correct values (for my purposes) for each row value of the data frame, but I can't find a way to nicely join all the individual values to the rest of the data frame.

So far, I have tried adding an empty row and then filling it using a for loop:

> ```
> bus78_uniM['travel_time'] <- NA
> for(i in 2:nrow(bus78_uniM)){
> bus78_uniM[i,11]<- bus78_uniM[Trav_time(bus78_uniM,i,5,6),11]
> }
> ```

But this returns the error message:

```
Error: Assigned data `bus78_uniM[Trav_time(bus78_uniM, i, 5, 6), 11]` must be compatible with row subscript `i`.
x 1 row must be assigned.
x Assigned data has 46955 rows.
i Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?
```

Was wondering if there was a better way to do this, or alternatively, a way to modify the function so that I can simply use the dplyr function sapply() instead.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Edit: A snapshot of the dataset:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMopd.png)

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example with `dput`.

Comment: `library(dplyr); Bus78uniM %>% mutate(tavel_time = time_col - lag(time_col))`?

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for my purposes as I need a condition that shows when there are missing rows in between the rows. The dataset has a several rows that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

If `travel_time` should contain the difference between *consecutive* rows, then you can use the `dplyr::lag` function. Below there is an example.
It's not clear to me what is the nature of the issue with the "missing rows inbetween the rows". Maybe you can provide a sample of your actual data (using `dput`) and describe the issue in details.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(124)
lags <- sample.int(100, 10)
departure <-  ymd_hms("2022-06-04 12:00:00")

tibble(sec = lags)  %>% 
  mutate(timestamp = departure + cumsum(sec)) %>% 
  mutate(lagged_timestamp = lag(timestamp, default = departure)) %>% 
  mutate(interval = timestamp - lagged_timestamp)
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
     sec timestamp           lagged_timestamp    interval
   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>  
 1    65 2022-06-04 12:01:05 2022-06-04 12:00:00  65 secs
 2   167 2022-06-04 12:03:52 2022-06-04 12:01:05 167 secs
 3   155 2022-06-04 12:06:27 2022-06-04 12:03:52 155 secs
 4     5 2022-06-04 12:06:32 2022-06-04 12:06:27   5 secs
 5   134 2022-06-04 12:08:46 2022-06-04 12:06:32 134 secs
 6   173 2022-06-04 12:11:39 2022-06-04 12:08:46 173 secs
 7    74 2022-06-04 12:12:53 2022-06-04 12:11:39  74 secs
 8   161 2022-06-04 12:15:34 2022-06-04 12:12:53 161 secs
 9   143 2022-06-04 12:17:57 2022-06-04 12:15:34 143 secs
10    91 2022-06-04 12:19:28 2022-06-04 12:17:57  91 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution! Thank you to everyone who responded to the post - it really helped me put it all together. I ended up creating a vector using the for loop, and then adding the vector to the dataset. Also modified the original function so that all the outputs were of type 'numeric'.

```
my_vec = c() for(i in 1:nrow(bus78_uniM)){ c<-Trav_time(bus78_uniM,i,5,6 my_vec<-c(my_vec,c)} bus78_uniM['travel_time'] <- my_vec
```

I apologize for the formatting - still learning how to use stack.overflow